# Owncloud error in Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: mysql, owncloud-server

I have installed Owncloud 7.0 on Ubuntu Server 14.04 on 2014 and it was working fine until last December, when we could not connect to the URL of Owncloud.
We receive a blank page through Mozilla and page isn't working through Hrom. I tried many thinks I've googled but no hope.
I upgraded Ubuntu to 16.04 and also `apache2` and `php` to have working sites. Also I tried to upgrade Owncloud from 7.0 to 8.0 and made some. And still  I cannot get a start page on Owncloud. Also I cannot connect to `mysql` database.
Please some advice.

With this command  `ps -ef | grep mysql` I receive this:

```
mysql    19531     1  0 Feb07 ?        00:00:23 /usr/sbin/mysqld
root     23304 23044  0 11:57 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

With this command `dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql` I receive:

```
libmysqlclient20:i386                           install
libqt4-sql-mysql:i386                           install
mysql-client-5.7                                install
mysql-client-core-5.7                           install
mysql-common                                    install
mysql-server                                    install
mysql-server-5.5                                deinstall
mysql-server-5.7                                install
mysql-server-core-5.7                           install
php5-mysql                                      deinstall
php7.0-mysql                                    install
```

Comment: What happens if you do mysql -u root -p on the command line? Can you check the error_log (usually in /var/log/apache2/) for the owncloud site for a error message?

Can you check your mysql error log, ususally in /var/log/mysql/).

It looks like mysql is running.